# javascript count objects in array of objects without null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's say we have array of objects:

```
const data = [
  {
    firstName: "Bruce",
    lastName: "Wayne",
    address: "Arkham 6",
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Peter",
    lastName: "Parker",
     address: "LA 54",
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Tony",
    lastName: "Stark",
    address: null,
    id: "3"
  }
];
```

and want to get length of the array but exclude counting of the objects which has null values (in example above, this is the last object with address property `null`) so that result of the counting of the example above would be 2.

```
objectsWithoutNull = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    return r + +( a!== null);
}, 0);
```

I'm trying with reduce method, but got 0.
Where is the problem in iteration?

Comment: do you want to look at a specific property or at all properties?

Comment: change to `a.address!== null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array, for each object get the values with `Object.values()`, and check with `Array.includes()` if it contains a `null` value. Negate with `!` the boolean result of inclues, and use the `+` operator to convert to number. Add the number to the accumulator.

```js
const data = [{"firstName":"Bruce","lastName":"Wayne","address":"Arkham 6","id":"1"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Parker","address":"LA 54","id":"2"},{"firstName":"Tony","lastName":"Stark","address":null,"id":"3"}];

const result = data.reduce((r, o) => 
  r + +!Object.values(o).includes(null)
, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `filter()` the array and than get `object values` and check where not `includes` null.

```js
const data = [
  {
    firstName: "Bruce",
    lastName: "Wayne",
    address: "Arkham 6",
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Peter",
    lastName: "Parker",
     address: "LA 54",
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Tony",
    lastName: "Stark",
    address: null,
    id: "3"
  }
];

const notNullable = data.filter(obj=>!Object.values(obj).includes(null));
console.log(notNullable)
console.log(notNullable.length)
```

More about [Object Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)  [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  [Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

An option is to iterate over the object-values of a and test if the value is equal to null. If we found a null don't increase our counter.

```js
const data = [
  {
    firstName: "Bruce",
    lastName: "Wayne",
    address: "Arkham 6",
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    firstName: "Peter",
    lastName: "Parker",
     address: "LA 54",
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Tony",
    lastName: "Stark",
    address: null,
    id: "3"
  }
];

let objectsWithoutNull = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
  let hasNull = false;
  const values = Object.values(a);
  values.map(v => {
    if (v === null) {
      hasNull = true;
    }
  });
  
  return r + !hasNull;
}, 0);

console.log(objectsWithoutNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  objectsWithoutNull = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + +( Object.values(a).indexOf(null) == -1);
    }, 0);
```

This will work if you want to check for all the properties!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.every to check that all the values are not null

```
var length = data.filter(i => Object.values(i).every(i => i !== null)).length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash.

```
const data = [
      {
        firstName: "Bruce",
        lastName: "Wayne",
        address: "Arkham 6",
        id: "1",
      },
      {
        firstName: "Peter",
        lastName: "Parker",
         address: "LA 54",
        id: "2"
      },
      {
        firstName: "Tony",
        lastName: "Stark",
        address: null,
        id: "3"
      }
    ];

const counter = _.filter(data, ({address}) => {return address != null}).length;
console.log(counter);
```